# VBA find nearest value in range of values based on specified criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook with two sheets.

Sheet 1 contains two columns - column1 has legs eg. Paris - London, Berlin - Warsaw etc. Column2 has some number values. Sheet 2 is bulit exactly in the same way as sheet1.

My goal is to create vba code which will take leg from sheet1 eg Paris - London and it find closest value from sheet2.

For example if in sheet1 Paris - London has value 10, and in sheet2 Paris - London has value 9,75 and 11 and 8,5 - I want macro to find that closest value for Paris -London in sheet2 is 9.75.

I have already done this calculation in excel by using Index(Match(if(min(abs) nesting but I can't do the same in VBA

I tried to use excel formula `=INDEX(sheet2!J:J,MATCH(MIN(IF(O2=sheet2!D:D,ABS(sheet2!J:J-S2))),IF(O2=sheet2!D:D,ABS(sheet2!J:J-S2)),0))` in vba but the problem is that I don't know how to manage these "IF" in the middle of the formula, as there is no worksheet function IF in vba

Comment: If you got a working formula in Excel you may benefit from [Evaluate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) in VBA. If you want to do it with *pure* VBA probably you'll need to learn about [conditionals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements) and maybe some [Worksheet Funcion in VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction)